# Replace taxonomy term with an image in a custom loop

Tags: custom-taxonomy, images

Just as the title says i want to replace the term from a custom taxonomy with an image, but **only in one custom loop** and not in the main loop.

So i have a custom taxonomy named Tax1 that has two terms: Term1 and Term2.
I use the following code to list the terms (i.e. Term1 or Term2) in the main loop:

`echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'Tax1', ' ', ', ', '' );`

But for my custom loop i would like to have **an image** instead of the text term.
I think this should be possible but i'm no good with php.

**So how can i achieve this?**

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick and easy solution if you only have two terms and don't need a way to change those pictures in the backend.

It assumes that inside your theme you have a folder "term_imgs" with *.png files names according to the slugs of your terms.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'Tax1' );
$out = array();
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $out[] = '<a href="'.get_term_link( $term->slug, 'Tax1' ) .'"><img alt="'.$term->name.'" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/term_imgs/'.$term->slug.'.png"></a>';
      }
      echo implode(',', $out );
    }
}
```

You can call this folder however you want, just change the according piece of code, e.g.

```
$out[] = '<a href="'.get_term_link( $term->slug, 'Tax1' ) .'"><img alt="'.$term->name.'" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/other_folder/'.$term->slug.'.jpg"></a>';
```

Comment: it works, but only for the first post in the loop. The second post has 2 images (for both terms), the third has 3 images and so on...

Comment: I just updated my answer. $out needs to be reset.